# MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer locks main thread with _establishConnectionIfNeeded on iOS 14.5

Tags: ios, swift, mpmusicplayercontroller

An app that should play music now locks the main thread with following errors:

> [SDKPlayback] applicationQueuePlayer _establishConnectionIfNeeded timeout [ping did not pong]
> [SDKPlayback] SYNC-WATCHDOG-1: Attempting to wake up the remote process
> [SDKPlayback] SYNC-WATCHDOG-2: Tearing down connection

Main thread is used as requested in MPMusicPlayerController documentation.

This happens with the .play() instruction:

```
private var musicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer
// ....

musicPlayer.setQueue(with: selectedMediaItemCollection)
musicPlayer.shuffleMode = .songs
musicPlayer.repeatMode = .all
musicPlayer.play()
```

When the App starts, those errors are also visible even though I only request local music access:

> [core] "Error returned from daemon: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=9 "(null)""
> [Default] ACAccountStore 0x280fe13b0 - Error retrieving iTunesStore accounts. err=Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=9 "(null)"
> [Default] ACAccountStore 0x280fe13b0 - Error retrieving iTunesStore accounts. err=Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=9 "(null)"

But there is also this that may be more damaging:

> [Default] ACAccountStore 0x280fe13b0 - Error retrieving local store account. err=Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=9 "(null)"
> [Default] [ICUserIdentityStore] Failed to fetch local store account with error: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=9 "(null)"

This code was working prior to iOS 14.5.

Any idea for a fix or workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to iOS 14.5.1 fixed it.

But the problem just reappeared with iOS 14.8... I filed a TSI with Apple.

Comment: This is crazy! So much time trying to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's recommended to call `prepareToPlay()` before executing the `play()` command:

```
    musicPlayerController.prepareToPlay { (error) in
        if let e = error {
            print(e)
        }
        self.musicPlayerController.play()
    }
```

Comment: Apple says "The system automatically calls this method on playback, but calling it in advance minimizes the delay between calling play() and the start of sound output". In my case, It is not needed.

Comment: True (in theory), but I've just seen this Watchdog error noted and been solved by making it explicit

Comment: As the problem reappeared with iOS 14.8, I tried this suggestion without any success.